# adding up down motion to a line in canvas html5

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to add a normal up and down motion to my two lines drawn in html5 using canvas . but i am unable to..
Kindly suggest me a way to overcome this and is there any better way to do this. 
I am adding the function here

```
function create_blades()
{

canvas_context.moveTo(60+x_pos,80);
canvas_context.lineTo(125+x_pos,40+y_factor);
canvas_context.lineWidth = 3;
canvas_context.stroke();

canvas_context.moveTo(60+x_pos,110);
canvas_context.lineTo(125+x_pos,60-y_factor);
canvas_context.lineWidth = 3;
canvas_context.stroke();
//motion();

 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to jsFiddle...Also mention on what action do you want the motion of the lines....(For these kind of work I would suggest "http://kineticjs.com/" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not describing the motion so here is a generic approach to animate lines (or any objects).

- Update positions
- Check boundaries/criterias
- Clear canvas
- Redraw shape
- Loop

Here is a **[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/WEbhf/)**.

```
var xpos = 0,  // holds current position (here, actually delta to fixed pos)
    ypos = 0,
    dltY = 2,  // delta values
    dltX = 2;

(function loop() {

    xpos += dltX; // add delta values
    ypos += dltY;

    // check boundaries, here canvas edges
    if (xpos < 0 || xpos > canvas.width) dltX = -dltX;    
    if (ypos < 0 || ypos > canvas.height) dltY = -dltY;    

    // redraw graphics
    create_blades(xpos, ypos);

    // loop
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

Then the draw function:

```
function create_blades(x_pos, y_factor) {

    // clear canvas
    canvas_context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    canvas_context.beginPath(); // need this first

    canvas_context.moveTo(60 + x_pos, 80);
    canvas_context.lineTo(125 + x_pos, 40 + y_factor);
    //canvas_context.lineWidth = 3; // not needed here
    //canvas_context.stroke();

    canvas_context.moveTo(60 + x_pos, 110);
    canvas_context.lineTo(125 + x_pos, 60 - y_factor);
    canvas_context.lineWidth = 3;
    canvas_context.stroke();
    //motion();
}
```

As you are using fixed values in the draw position the passed arguments with positions will of course just add to that, but you should be able to see the principle in how you move the shape.

Comment: thanx a lot...can u please suggest me any good way of doing this.i mean any library that will help me create these animations properly .thanx in advance